# What does it mean by "dynamics of a sequence" mathematically?

Tags: terminology, math, sequence-modeling, statistical-ai

Consider the following paragraph from the topic named [sequential models](https://d2l.ai/chapter_recurrent-neural-networks/sequence.html#statistical-tools) from the textbook titled [Dive into Deep Learning](https://d2l.ai/)

> Both cases raise the obvious question of how to generate training
> data. One typically uses historical observations to predict the next
> observation given the ones up to right now. Obviously we do not expect
> time to stand still. However, a common assumption is that while the
> specific values of might change, **at least the dynamics of the
> sequence itself will not**. This is reasonable, since novel dynamics
> are just that, novel and thus not predictable using data that we have
> so far. Statisticians call dynamics that do not change stationary.

Here sequence refers to $x_1, x_2, x_3, \cdots, x_t$. Say the stock price of  a company.

What does it mean rigorously by the dynamics of a sequence in statistics?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any rigorous mathematical definition of dynamic, or to phrase it better, the definition is embedded in the definition of *dynamical system* itself (which would be probably a better term to use in place of the generic "sequence"):

> A dynamical system is formally defined as a state space $X$, a set of
> time points $T$, and a rule $R$ that specifies how the state evolves with time.
> The rule $R$ is a function whose domain is $X×T$ and whose
> codomain is $X$, i.e., $R:X×T→X$. The rule function $R$ means
> that the $R$ takes two inputs, $R=R(x,t)$, where $x∈X$ is an
> initial state and $t∈T$ is a specific time step.

I think that what the paragraph states is that we assume the rule funcion R to remain the same, cause that's what we're trying to learn.

As a final note, there are out there also [classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_system#Types_of_nonlinear_dynamic_behaviors) of different non-linear dynamical systems, based on the property of $R$.